# Is it necessary or proper to put semicolons after a comment in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, comments

So, I am writing a rather long javascript file. I understand that it is proper to insert semicolons after each line in javascript, and do so religiously.

However, I am using a lot of comments in my code, and was curious as to whether it is proper, necessary, or even effectual at the end of a comment. For example, do I need to write my one line comments like this:

```
// Comment here;
```

rather than like this:

```
// Comment here
```

or would it be better to use the

```
/*comment here*/
```

notation for comments?

Comment: I don't remember coming across a comment ending with a semi colon.  I think it's fine to just use block comments or //

Comment: It isn't necessary or proper. Use /*comment here*/ for multi-line comments and // for single

Comment: Semicolons go after the end of a statement (or whatever the term is for js). After every line is completely unnecessary and may result in bugs (e.g., `if(a === b);/*line ends here*/killEverybodyInTheWorld();` placing the semi at the end of the if statement terminates it, so killEverybodyInTheWorld executes immediately)  What you're doing is called "cargo cult programming"--you're coding something because you've seen it done and don't understand it.  Try to understand something before you repeat it.

Comment: @Will everybody knows that you don't put a semicolon at the end of a conditional statement before the code that it executes. I was making a generalization.

Comment: Well, I thought everybody knew you didn't put a semicolon at the end of a comment.  Guess we all learned something new today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments are ignored by all JavaScript engines. You can choose to put a semicolon at the end of your comments, but it will have no effect whatsoever. I have personally never seen anyone use that style when commenting.

Answer (score 0):

JSHint would call it an unnecassary semicolon, so simply No.

Edit: In the airbnb style guide, at the comment section there aren't semicolons either - https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#comments

Comment: How <s>the hell</s> is the AirBnB company's style guidelines a definitive answer for the question?  Some other company may say they are necessary and proper.

Comment: Then use the google one. http://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml#Comments but I recommend using a well known style guide. If you are developing in a closed environment like your own company, you could have your own style guide but how should I know about your company?

Comment: Better to quote ecmascript specs rather than ANY company's style guidelines.